# Vue app not using localstorage after login (vue router)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I store the user key in localstorage and redirect the user to the dashboard after successful login my application is not using the stored key until after a refresh.

This is the code that sets the key.

```
    axios.post(url, creds)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.code === 401) {
          context.error = response.data.data
        } else {
          Vue.ls.set('id_token', response.data.data.key, 60 * 60 * 1000)
          this.user.authenticated = true
        }
      }).catch((err) => {
        context.error = err.data
      })
```

The funny thing is that I have a route guard in a beforeEach, this actually uses the right value right after the login, without a refresh.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const r = axios.create({
    baseURL: env.api_url,
    timeout: 25000,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Vue.ls.get('id_token'),
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
  })

  if (to.name === 'Login') {
    r.get('user').then(() => {
      next({name: 'Dashboard'})
    }).catch(() => {
      next({name: 'Login'})
    })
  }

  if (to.name !== 'Login') {
    r.get('user').then(() => {
      next()
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      next({name: 'Login'})
    })
  } else next()
})
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: `Vue.ls.set` is probably an asynchronous function. Maybe route change before `Vue.ls.set` has completed

Comment: @JacobGoh This was my first thought, but when browsing the app all the API calls return unauthenticated until I refresh the page. If I inspect the API calls the bearer token is empty. But, when I look in local storage the token is actually present. It simply is not used until a full page refresh.

Comment: I am not sure about `vue-ls` but for my projects I use my own custom `localStorage` service, which gives me more confidence. And for tokens I believe it's more convenient to use global `axios interceptor`

Comment: @SazzadurRahman Can you give an example of your localStorage implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to JacobGoh's comment I managed to find the issue. I created the axios instance in my main.js file. This is where I set the Authorization headers. When a user logs in this is not updated.

I did the following instead:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (Vue.ls.get('id_token') === null && to.name !== 'Login' && to.name !== 'Register') {
    router.push('/login')
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

Vue.$http.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + Vue.ls.get('id_token')
    return config
  },
  error => Promise.reject(error)
)
```

Works like a charm.